# MySQL - Selecting Count with multiple tables and conditions for each

Tags: mysql, count

I am having a rather simple query in mind:

I have three tables and I want to return the count of the rows which are used (have foreign key) of each table.

This was my first attempt:

```
    SELECT 
        COUNT(at.code) AS atcount, 
        COUNT(de.code) AS decount, 
        COUNT(ch.code) AS chcount 
    FROM 
        table_at at, 
        table_ch ch, 
        table_de de 
    WHERE 
        at.teilnehmerid != 0
    AND
        de.teilnehmerid != 0
    AND
        ch.teilnehmerid != 0
```

But this somehow does not work, it does not generate any error, but the conditions are just not considered. I also thought about about subqueries, like:

```
    SELECT 
        (SELECT COUNT(code) FROM table_at at WHERE at.teilnehmerid != 0), 
        (SELECT COUNT(code) FROM table_de de WHERE de.teilnehmerid != 0), 
        (SELECT COUNT(code) FROM table_ch ch WHERE ch.teilnehmerid != 0)
```

But I was confused about something rather stupid with this attempt... what about the `FROM`?
Of course I am getting an error: `Operand should contain 1 column(s)` - but I just want the counts...

I also read about Joins, but did not understand how to get the `COUNT` via a `JOIN` inside my main `SELECT` statement.

And yeah I have read some other questions around here, but did not see an answer applying to both problems:

- selecting multiple tables

AND

- doing a `COUNT` on multiple table

If I am wrong and just did not get the answer right, maybe a better explanation would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `COUNT()` returns a single row, single column; how about,

```
SELECT * 
FROM
(SELECT COUNT(code) FROM table_at at WHERE teilnehmerid != 0) as T1, 
(SELECT COUNT(code) FROM table_de de WHERE teilnehmerid != 0) as T2, 
(SELECT COUNT(code) FROM table_ch ch WHERE teilnehmerid != 0) as T3
```

where the joins would return one row.

Comment: Looked promising, but does not work, I am fetching the result as an array in php, and `$row['T1']` is empty, as well as T2 and T3 and I can assure there are multiple rows meeting the condition.

Comment: Ah sorry, my mistake, T1 does not refer to the values given back :-) `$row[0]` - `$row[2]` return the values

Answer (score 1):

`COUNT (x)` very different than `COUNT(DISTINCT x)`. The former counts all values with multiplicity, the latter counts only distinct values. Perhaps the latter is what you want to use.

Comment: As far as I read about `DISTINCT` it is not what I am looking for, because my condition does not refer to selecting a single column, but selecting certain rows, with a certain value in that column.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to join the tables to get the result, but without seeing the table structures and how they relate it is difficult.

You can get the results the following way, using a `UNION ALL`:

```
select count(code) CodeCount, 'atcount' col
from table_at
where teilnehmerid != 0
union all
select count(code) CodeCount, 'chcount' col
from table_ch
where teilnehmerid != 0
union all
select count(code) CodeCount, 'decount' col
from table_de
where teilnehmerid != 0
```

This will give you the values in a single column and then if you want them in a row you can use the following:

```
select 
    max(case when x.col = 'atcount' then x.codecount else 0 end) atcount,
    max(case when x.col = 'chcount' then x.codecount else 0 end) chcount,
    max(case when x.col = 'decount' then x.codecount else 0 end) decount
from 
(
    select count(code) CodeCount, 'atcount' col
    from table_at
    where teilnehmerid != 0
    union all
    select count(code) CodeCount, 'chcount' col
    from table_ch
    where teilnehmerid != 0
    union all
    select count(code) CodeCount, 'decount' col
    from table_de
    where teilnehmerid != 0
) x
```

Comment: I tried the second one, cause I like using appropiate approaches, as far as I do unterstand them, unfortunately this was not the case for me. It might not work because above you are calling it "codecount" and below "CodeCount", also I am not sure what the "x" in the end means, is it the naming like `AS x`? I believe your answer is right as well, just could not prove it for me, but it will be surely helpful for other users, therefore +1

Comment: @SamiSalami the `CodeCount` is just the alias for the count column, you can call it whatever you want.  The `X` is the alias for the subquery, each subquery needs to have an alias, again you can rename it. This is getting all of the values in the column format and then rotating them to a single row.